# Openshift 3 Deployment Error: update acceptor rejected

Tags: openshift

It's been several weeks now and I still have not been able to deploy my Openshift 3 Pyramid Starter App.  Openshift has put my app on the "starter-us-west-1" servers.

[Openshift 3 Pyramid Starter App Repo](https://github.com/fatfantasma/Openshift_3_Pyramid_Starter)

The app builds fine but I get the following error when trying to deploy:

**Logs**

```
--> Scaling os3-pyramid-starter-5 to 1
--> Waiting up to 10m0s for pods in rc os3-pyramid-starter-5 to become ready
error: update acceptor rejected os3-pyramid-starter-5: pods for rc "os3-pyramid-starter-5" took longer than 600 seconds to become ready
```

Is Openshift 3 starter still having issues with building and deploying?  I know there are open issues on the Openshift status page but it's been several weeks already.  I'm not sure if it's my problem or Openshift's.  The app runs correctly on my localhost.

[Openshift Status](https://status.starter.openshift.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This was an Openshift 3 error.  I was able to build and deploy today.

Comment: which version you are running?

Comment: Openshift 3 starter

Comment: Hmm, doesn't help much. OpenShift details would be useful